# Congratulations for birth of child

Tags: phrase

What is a commonly used phrase to congratulate someone for the birth of a child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С новорОжденным (вас)! (more typical between friends or relatives)

C пополнением в семье! (more widely used)

Comment: новорожд**ё**нным

Comment: Форма с "ё" считается основной, но конкретно это приветствие тяготеет к форме с безударным  "е" - так произносит его подавляющее большинство носителей языка. Словари по-разному относятся к этим словам: в одних они равноценны, в других вариант с "е" отнесён к просторечному употреблению. Есть и монографии, агрессивно требующие повсеместно только произношения с "ё" (цитата: " ... практически все ставят его [ударение] неверно..." - как говорится, I rest my case :) ). Моё мнение - при выборе нужно считаться с контекстом.

Comment: Так и написали бы в ответе, что есть норма и просторечие, которое лично вы предпочитаете. Любопытно было бы полистать словарь, в котором они равноценны. Не припомните, в каком?

Comment: Словарь Ожегова. Там нет пометки о просторечности и есть другой пример с таким произношением. http://enc-dic.com/ozhegov/Novorozhdennyj-18795.html

Comment: Интересно, в каком году появился второй вариант и была ли когда-то помета. В издании 1964 г. вариант один.

Comment: И ещё есть Кузнецов - там отмечено как "(разг.)", академическое издание 2000 года. Примеры, естественно, привязаны к основному варианту словарной статьи. Приветствие же "С новорожденным", на устойчивом характере произношения которого я настаиваю, обойдено стороной, как и в других словарях. http://bookre.org/loader/img.php?dir=c5bb168259919aacee840377e33444f5&file=655.png Кузнецова все активные борцы за единственно возможный вариант произношения считают нужным упомянуть и говорят, что он на самом деле имел в виду не то, что можно подумать :).

Comment: А чем уникально именно приветствие? "Устойчивый характер" ведь не у него, а у самого слова. Равно как и у многих других, устойчиво и массово употребляемых "неправильно". Кстати, забавно, что в издании Шведовой (я так понимаю, она добавила вторую норму) _незаконнорождённый_ без вариантов.

Comment: Одна из особенностей - отсутствие существительного после слова "новорожденный", которое в результате само используется подобно существительному. В сочетании со словом "ребёнок" я бы и сам выбрал вариант "новорождённый".